# How to make a separate Class for making new record at table and call it via an Interface or a Facade at the Controller

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, interface, laravel-8

I want to refactor my Controller code which is creating a new record at table `products`:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
       $newPro = Product::create([
                'name' => $request->product_name,
                'en_name' => $request->product_name_english,
                'type' => $request->product_type,
                'cat_id' => $request->category_product,
       ]);
       ...
     }
```

Now in order to refactor this code, I have two options:

**1-** Create a separate method at the same Controller and then call it like this:

```
$newPro = self::createProduct($request->product_name,$request->product_name_english,$request->product_type,$request->category_product)
```

**2-** Create a separate Class and call it by the `interface` or `facade` (Best way)

Now I wanted to use the 2nd option but I don't know really how to!

So if you know please let me know...

Comment: So you want to use Repository Pattern actually?

Comment: @gguney Yes sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First create your repository service provider:

```
php artisan make:provider RepositoryServiceProvider
```

then you should map Interface and your Repository (ofcourse you must create ProductRepository and ProductRepositoryInterface too) inside register method like:

```
/**
 * Register services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(ProductRepositoryInterface::class, ProductRepository::class);

}
```

after that you can inject your repository to your controller like:

```
public function store(Request $request, ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository)
{
    $newPro = $productRepository->createProduct($productData);
    ...
}
```

Here is your **ProductRepository**:

```
<?php
namespace App\Repositories;

class ProductRepository extends BaseRepository implements ProductRepositoryInterface
{
    protected Product $product;

    /**
     * @param  Product  $product
     */
    public function __construct(Product $product)
    {
        $this->product = $product;
    }

    /**
     * @param  array  $productArray
     * @return Product
     */
    public function createProduct(array $productArray): Product
    {
        return $this->product->create($productArray);
    }
}
```

and your ProductRepositoryInterface:

```
<?php

namespace App\Repositories;

interface CategoryRepositoryInterface
{
    /**
     * @param  array  $productArray
     * @return Product
     */
    public function createProduct(array $productArray): Product;
}
```